# sqlplus DELETE statement

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

I'm using sqlplus (oracle). I trying to write a statement to remove all authors that have not yet published a book based on the bookauthor table. 
Since I have joined to tables , I don't know how to delete authors that have not yet published a book. Also I'm not sure If I got subquery correctly in order to get an output of authors who have not published a book.

```
DELETE 
FROM bookauthor, books
WHERE authorid = 
(SELECT authorid, count(*) pubdate
FROM   bookauthor 
JOIN books USING (isbn)
GROUP BY authorid
HAVING count(*) < 1);
```

This is what I have so far.
I can't get it run correctly.

For table `books` -> isbn, title, pubdate, pubid, cost, retail, discount, category
for table `bookauthor` -> isbn, authorid

Comment: *I can't get it run correctly* is not a useful problem description, and *please help!* is not a question. What specific problem are you having with the SQL you posted?

Comment: since I have joined to tables , I don't know how to delete authors that have not yet published a book. Also I'm not sure If I got subquery correctly in order to get an output of authors who have not published a book.

Comment: You can see if your subquery is correct by running it by itself. Also, you can't delete from multiple tables at once (`DELETE FROM bookauthor, books`). Actually, you should never have a comma in your `WHERE` clause, because that means you're not using a proper JOIN. You may also want to consider `NOT EXISTS` as an option.

Comment: What Ken meant with his first comment is that "I can't get it run correctly" doesn't tell us what is happening. Do you get an error when running the statement or are too many rows deleted or too few? (Well, seeing the statement it's obvious, that you'll get an error, but you shouldn't have us guess, but tell us the exact error message instead.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE 
FROM bookauthor
WHERE authorid =
                (SELECT authorid FROM bookauthor WHERE isbn NOT IN (SELECT isbn FROM books))
```

Try this.

```
DELETE 
FROM bookauthor
WHERE authorid =
                (SELECT authorid FROM bookauthor a LEFT OUTER JOIN books b ON a.isbn = b.isbn WHERE b.isbn IS null)
```

Or this.

Answer (score 2):

There are several flaws in your delete statement:

1. You want to delete authors that haven't published a book. That means you should be looking for authors that have no entry in the bookauthor table. But you don't even mention any author table and `DELETE FROM bookauthor, books` instead, which makes no sense.
2. You compare `WHERE authorid = (SELECT authorid, count(*) FROM ...`. How can one ID possibly equal a pair of ID and count? It would have to be `WHERE authorid = (SELECT authorid FROM ...` instead.
3. In your subquery you are asking for `HAVING count(*) < 1`. But every author that is in the table occurs at least once of course. So this condition is never met. You are kind of asking: "Which of the authors in the bookauthor table is not in the bookauthor table?".

As mentioned, all this only makes sense with an author table:

> trying to write a statement to remove all **authors** that ...

You are showing two tables. The `book` table where each book is identified by its ISBN. And the `bookauthor` table that links books to authors. This is called a bridge table (or junction table or association table or ... ‐ well there are many names for this). It establishes an m:n relation between author and book, so one author can have many books and one book can be written by more than one author. (If you wanted an 1:n relation instead, so that a book can only be written by one author, then the author ID would be an attribute in the book table.) So there must be an `author` table you haven't shown that the `bookauthor` table is referring to.

It should be something like:

```
delete from author where authorid not in (select authorid from bookauthor);
```